# How to install Samba and Share directory and Printer

Tags: 12.10, samba

I am trying to get Samba working on Ubuntu to share a Directory and a Printer over the network to a Windows PC, only... when I install it I can't get the link for the GUI, and I can get no where with it. Could someone help me on how to set this up? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up doing this:

Don't use SAMBA. The CUPS already has a built in server (once enabled) @ `http://hostname:631/printers/PRINTERNAME`

For the directory, I forgot to install system-config-samba that serves as the GUI. And I edited the /etc/samba/smb.conf to get everything working.

Comment: CUPS is what works for ubuntu 12.10, I installed samba packages unnecessarily.. now I need to uninstall them w/o creating new problems (I think).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to defining the share in `smb.conf` as mentioned I also found it necessary to define SAMBA users (distinct from Ubuntu users):

For example to add a SAMBA user to your Ubuntu system with the user name jseinfeld, you would enter this command at the prompt:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a jseinfeld
```

The **smbpasswd** application will then prompt you to enter a password for the user:

```
New SMB password:
```

Enter the password you wish to set for the user, and the **smbpasswd** application will ask you to confirm the password:

```
Retype new SMB password:
```

Confirm the password, and **smbpasswd** will add the entry for the user to the SAMBA password file.

For further assistance, see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/configuring-samba.html

Comment: This is also good source of info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to get required shared configured.

Else use a wrapper tool like [zentyal](http://www.zentyal.com) which has smart interface to help you configure Samba. (a bit of learning curve will be there)