# Is there to tell if Ubuntu won't support certain printers?

Tags: networking, printing, dell, canon

My system can't find a driver for a Dell Photo 924 (I downloaded an executable installation app but it bombs). Also it can't seem to find my wireless network printer, a Canon MP560.
Thanks for any help...

Comment: There's a program called SAMBA, I'm sure one of the nice guys here is making a quick guide right now (:

Comment: does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213445/how-to-install-samba-and-share-directory-and-printer ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several online, user maintained databases. Typically they list compatible hardware, but not always. Most of the dirvers are in the kernel and not specific to Ubuntu.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/OpenPrinting/Database/DatabaseIntro

Answer (score 0):

Here is why you have problems when installing needed drivers for Dell: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/p/19270536/19471745.aspx.